# AngularCli: disable minification

Tags: angular-cli

Is there a way to disable the minification in AngularCli?

After I launch the command `ng build --prod` I need to have all files.js, in dist folder, separate and legible.

Comment: Is there any reason against using `ng build` without the `--prod` flag?

Comment: What happens if you build in non-prod mode? Also, why do you need all of the separate JS?

Comment: 'ng build --prod --source-map' will also generate source maps that your browser can use to show you the original code (for debugging). But using 'ng serve' (default dev mod) would be the best way to go about this.

Comment: Sorry, it is true that ng build disable minification. But what I want is that all files.js of each component are saved separately and not all in main.bundle.js

Comment: Interesting conversation. We have the same need : don't minifying (because of class renaming) some modules because of certain functionality. Any idea ?

Comment: If --prod is your production there is serious difference. 9M main.js file drops to 1.2M with minification.

Answer (score 73):

Just do:

```
ng build --prod --optimization=false
```

That seems to do it. For more information see: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

This is valid for angular 6.*

Comment: what about angular 5?

Comment: Don't know, sorry! Only started using Angular with versions 6.*+

Comment: C'est genial :-D I was trying to find out, what setting is responsible for file minification in published Angular site, specifically on typescript site, but could not! And then I found your post... :-D Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! :D

Answer (score 22):

**Note:** If you use **ng serve** through some package.json run target,
according to the manpage of **Angular6** correspoding switch for this is:

`ng serve --optimization=false`

will speedup this bs in development noticeable

Comment: Meaningful use. In prod it will cause fat output, but @devenv helps.

Comment: this was my trick, to see what provider fails to be injected! I was getting `Error: No provider for t`, now I get an error message more human `No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory!`

Comment: Today this option is [deprecated](https://angular.io/cli/serve#ng-serve) with `ng serve`, but it is possible to use it with `ng build` and by configuring the *angular.json* file

Comment: @fservantdev how do you do this please?

Comment: @fservantdev how do you do this?

Comment: You can check this more updated answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70995225/12292636

Answer (score 18):

The responses from 2018 are now outdated. For the more recent versions of Angular (13 as of this writing), the `--optimization=false` flag is deprecated. Instead, you can achieve the same result as follows:

In your `angular.json`, you can configure it for specific environment (e.g. no optimization in dev, but optimization in prod).

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "optimization": false,
            ...
          }
        }
      }
```

You can also have more granular control on which optimizations are enabled:

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "fonts": false,
  "styles": false
}
```

Those too can be further refined (e.g. for styles: `minify`, `inlineCritical`)

More details here:
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration

Comment: Best answer with the current versions of Angular

Answer (score 9):

```
ng build --build-optimizer=false
```

Above command Enables '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer' optimizations when using the 'aot' option.

More details at https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: running this does not prevent bundling and minification for me,

Comment: That did not disable JSUglify minification for me

Answer (score -3):

In order to get the plain and separate and un-minified js files you just need to **compile them with typescript** (`tsc`) to your `dist` directory.

There is no need to use the cli build. By design Angular CLI bundles all javascript files when building.

From the cli [build documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#bundling--tree-shaking):

> All builds make use of bundling and limited tree-shaking, while --prod builds also run limited dead code elimination via UglifyJS.

Comment: I dont think thats correct. Typescript cant compile angular templates

Comment: Also typescript doesn't create any bundle, it only outputs 1-to-1 .js translations of .ts files