# How do I get a better stack trace on Angular errors

Tags: angular, error-handling, stack-trace

Currently, when I get an error in my production Angular (v7) app, I get a stack trace like this.  But this is virtually impossible to get any meaningful information from.  How can I get a better stack trace, so that I could narrow down where this elusive error is coming from?  Right now, I'm living with this error in prod because it never happens on my development machine, and I have no idea how to isolate it because the stacktrace is virtually useless to me.  I am used to languages like C#, where you get a very concise stacktrace that gives you a map down to the function in error.  This stack trace has no meaning.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at create_dom_structure (eval at  (:15:1), :1:16231)
at load_map (eval at  (:15:1), :1:101028)
at Object.load (eval at  (:15:1), :1:107834)
at eval (eval at  (:15:1), :1:108251)
at t.invokeTask (https://mywebsite.com/polyfills.d8680adf69e7ebd1de57.js:1:8844)
at Object.onInvokeTask (https://mywebsite.com/main.25a9fda6ea42f4308b79.js:1:467756)
at t.invokeTask (https://mywebsite.com/polyfills.d8680adf69e7ebd1de57.js:1:8765)
at e.runTask (https://mywebsite.com/polyfills.d8680adf69e7ebd1de57.js:1:4026)
at e.invokeTask (https://mywebsite.com/polyfills.d8680adf69e7ebd1de57.js:1:9927)
at invoke (https://mywebsite.com/polyfills.d8680adf69e7ebd1de57.js:1:9818)
```

My error handler:

```
export class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

constructor(
    private _http: Http,
    private injector: Injector,
) {
    super();
}

public handleError(error: any): void {
    if (error.status === '401') {
        alert('You are not logged in, please log in and come back!');
    } else {
        const router = this.injector.get(Router);

        const reportOject = {
            status: error.status,
            name: error.name,
            message: error.message,
            httpErrorCode: error.httpErrorCode,
            stack: error.stack,
            url: location.href,
            route: router.url,
        };
        this._http.post(`${Endpoint.APIRoot}Errors/AngularError`, reportOject)
            .toPromise()
            .catch((respError: any) => {
                Utils.formatError(respError, `AppErrorHandler()`);
            });
    }
    super.handleError(error);
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally Javascript stack traces *are* more useful. Unfortunately, in a production application you generally turn on minification, which is why you get such an unreadable mess.

If you can afford a larger Javascript bundle, it may be useful to turn off the minification just to get a better stack trace in production.

How to do this will vary depending on which version of the Angular CLI you're using. For the v7 CLI:

In the file angular.json, set the following properties

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              ...
            }
    ...
}
```

Alternative solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557090/angularcli-disable-minification)

Comment: I agree, the minification is what is 'blurring' the stack trace.  I hate to turn it off, because there are many obvious benefits to using it, primarily performance, secondly, security.  But, I can afford to turn it off for now to diagnose this error.  So that is a good solution to my question.  I read the other post, but there doesn't appear to be a better way.

Perhaps I will open a feature request with Angular that they do something to make error handling a tad bit more useful.  The stack trace I presented above is not likely useful to anyone, making error handling almost useless.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a great solution. But assuming you have steps to reproduce the error in production, or it happens frequently, you can just turn it off, wait until you get a usable stack trace, and then turn it back on while you investigate

Answer (score 0):

The page below will take a stack trace then download the minified js and select 100 characters before and after the error location.  It will do that for all levels then display.

As is it must be accessed from the same domain with same deploy which stack trace was collected. I'm sure the same concept could be easily ported to node as to not have any cross domain or path limitations.

It also has a button that can replace base path with a backup path or secondary domain name.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <script>
    var updateUrl = false;

    const scriptFiles = new Map()
    var newDivGroup = null;

    function clickDecode(updateUrlNew) { 
      updateUrl = updateUrlNew;
      decodeNow();
    }

    async function decodeNow() {
      var textOutput = document.getElementById('text-output');
      textOutput.innerHTML = '';

      var myString = document.getElementById('text-input').value;
      // console.log(myString);
      var myRegexp = /(https:[a-zA-Z0-9\/\.]+.js):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/g;
      var matches = myString.matchAll(myRegexp);
      for (const match of matches) {
        newDivGroup = document.createElement("div");
        newDivGroup.style.marginBottom = '6px';
        newDivGroup.style.padding = '15px';
        newDivGroup.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
        newDivGroup.style.border = '1px solid #555'
        textOutput.appendChild(newDivGroup);

        // logToOutput('-');
        logToOutput(match[0]);
        await showErrorLocation(match[1], match[2], match[3])
      }
    }

    function logToOutput(message) {
      const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      const newContent = document.createTextNode(message);
      newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
      
      newDivGroup.appendChild(newDiv);
    }

    async function showErrorLocation(scriptUrl, row, position) {
      if(updateUrl) {
        scriptUrl = scriptUrl.toLowerCase();      
        scriptUrl = scriptUrl.replaceAll('/dist/', '/dist-old/');      
      }
      position = parseInt(position);
      if(!scriptFiles.has(scriptUrl)) {
        const fileContents = await downloadScriptFile(scriptUrl);
        scriptFiles.set(scriptUrl, fileContents);
      }
      const fileContents = scriptFiles.get(scriptUrl);
      const fileLines = fileContents.split('\n');
      const fileLine = fileLines[row - 1];

      let before = fileLine.substring(position - 100, position - 1);
      let after = fileLine.substring(position - 1, position + 100);
      logToOutput(before);
      logToOutput(after);
    }

    function downloadScriptFile(filePath) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', filePath);
        xhr.responseType = 'text';
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status != 200) {
            console.error(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
            reject();
          } else {
            // console.log(xhr.response);
            return resolve(xhr.response);
          }
        };
      });
    }
  </script>
<body style="padding: 30px;">

  <textarea id="text-input" rows="12" cols="150">

  </textarea>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="clickDecode(false)">Run (current deploy)</button>
  <button onclick="clickDecode(true)">Replace URL and Run (prior deploy)</button>
  <br/><br/>
  <div id="text-output">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED INFO FOR NEW ANGULAR VERSIONS

We have available some debugging aids for Angular:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/devtools-better-angular-debugging/

But in any case, **one of the new features of Angular 15 is
Better Stack Traces**:

With the launch of the latest version of Angular, debugging Angular applications has been simplified and is now more straightforward with stack traces.
Angular’s development team strives to achieve a standard for tracing development code irrespective of displaying libraries during the entire Angular development lifecycle.

The primary aim of developing such stack traces is to improve the display of error messages as they come by. For example, developers get a one-liner error message during the code discovery phase if we talk about the previous versions of Angular. And a lot more to deal with the lengthy procedure to resolve that bug.

First, let’s see the snippet for previous error indications:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
Error
   at app.component.ts:18:11
   at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
   at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
   at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
   at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
   at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26378:33)
   at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:52)
   at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
   at zone.js:1275:36
   at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
   at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
   at zone.js:1118:17
   at zone.js:1134:33
```

Developers were not able to understand the ERROR snippets due the following reasons:

```
Third-party dependencies were solely responsible for such error message inputs.
You were not getting any information related to where such user interaction encountered this bug.
With an active and long collaboration with the Angular and Chrome DevTool team, it was pretty useful for the Angular community to perform integration with third-party dependencies (with the help of node_modules, zone.js, etc.); and thus, could achieve linked stack traces.
```

**Now, with Angular 15, you can see the improvement in the stack traces** as mentioned below:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
Error
   at app.component.ts:18:11
   at fetch (async) 
   at (anonymous) (app.component.ts:4)
   at request (app.component.ts:4)
   at (anonymous) (app.component.ts:17)
   at submit (app.component.ts:15)
   at AppComponent_click_3_listener (app.component.html:4)
```

The above code shows that error message information from where it got encountered,, so developers can directly go to that code part and fix it immediately.

SOURCE:

https://devtechnosys.com/insights/latest-angular-v15-features/

https://www.albiorixtech.com/blog/angular-15-best-features-new-updates/

Comment: Actually, it is still not very helpful event with the improvements for all errors. For example, I am getting this error reported:
`Network Error Error: Network Error 
    at https://app.foo.com/main.5453af8ff0d6278e.js:1:22306
    at https://app.foo.com/main.5453af8ff0d6278e.js:1:641403
    at R._error (https://app.foo.com/main.5453af8ff0d6278e.js:1:640869)
` and it doesn't really tell me what R is

Answer (score 0):

We collect stack traces on the client machine automatically for later review.
When collecting them that way we still see ex. `bd3678935.js:1:182779` which is line 1 column 182779.
If you have source maps enabled here is a better version.
It uses the [source-map](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map) library to display the actual source code lines and puts a red marked for the column postilion.

Enabling source map does change your prod script file hash since there is a reference to the source map in the js file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Content/lib/source-map.js"></script>
    <script>
        const sourceMap = window.sourceMap;
        sourceMap.SourceMapConsumer.initialize({
            "lib/mappings.wasm": "../Content/lib/mappings.wasm",
        });

        const scriptFiles = new Map()
        var newDivGroup = null;

        async function decodeNow(version) {
            var textOutput = document.getElementById('text-output');
            textOutput.innerHTML = '';

            var myString = document.getElementById('text-input').value;
            // console.log(myString);
            var myRegexp = /(https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(?::\d{1,4})?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/\.]+.js):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/g;
            var matches = myString.matchAll(myRegexp);
            for (const match of matches) {
                newDivGroup = document.createElement("div");
                newDivGroup.style.marginBottom = '6px';
                newDivGroup.style.padding = '15px';
                newDivGroup.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
                newDivGroup.style.border = '1px solid #555'
                textOutput.appendChild(newDivGroup);

                logToOutput(match[0]);
                if (version === 1) {
                    await showErrorLocation(match[1], match[2], match[3])
                } else {
                    await showErrorLocationSourceMap(match[1], match[2], match[3]);
                }
            }
        }

        function logToOutput(message) {
            const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.style.setProperty('white-space', 'pre');
            const newContent = document.createTextNode(message);
            newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

            newDivGroup.appendChild(newDiv);
        }

        async function showErrorLocation(scriptUrl, row, position) {
            position = parseInt(position);
            if (!scriptFiles.has(scriptUrl)) {
                const fileContents = await downloadScriptFile(scriptUrl);
                scriptFiles.set(scriptUrl, fileContents);
            }
            const fileContents = scriptFiles.get(scriptUrl);
            const fileLines = fileContents.split('\n');
            const fileLine = fileLines[row - 1];

            let before = fileLine.substring(position - 100, position - 1);
            let after = fileLine.substring(position - 1, position + 100);
            logToOutput(before);
            logToOutput(after);
        }

        async function showErrorLocationSourceMap(scriptUrl, row, position) {
            scriptUrl = scriptUrl + '.map';
            position = parseInt(position);
            if (!scriptFiles.has(scriptUrl)) {
                const fileContents = await downloadScriptFile(scriptUrl);
                scriptFiles.set(scriptUrl, fileContents);
            }

            const fileContents = scriptFiles.get(scriptUrl);
            var fileContentsJson = JSON.parse(fileContents);

            await sourceMap.SourceMapConsumer.with(fileContentsJson, null, consumer => {
                var sourcePosition = consumer.originalPositionFor({ line: parseInt(row), column: parseInt(position) });
                if (sourcePosition.source) {
                    logToOutput(`${sourcePosition.source}:${sourcePosition.line}:${sourcePosition.column}`);
                    sourceFile = consumer.sourceContentFor(sourcePosition.source, true);
                    sourceFile = sourceFile.split('\n');

                    const table1 = document.createElement("table");
                    const tbody1 = document.createElement("tbody");
                    table1.appendChild(tbody1);

                    logCodeTableRow(tbody1, sourcePosition.line - 4, sourcePosition.column, false, sourceFile[sourcePosition.line - 4]);
                    logCodeTableRow(tbody1, sourcePosition.line - 3, sourcePosition.column, false, sourceFile[sourcePosition.line - 3]);
                    logCodeTableRow(tbody1, sourcePosition.line - 2, sourcePosition.column, false, sourceFile[sourcePosition.line - 2]);
                    logCodeTableRow(tbody1, sourcePosition.line - 1, sourcePosition.column, true, sourceFile[sourcePosition.line - 1]);
                    logCodeTableRow(tbody1, sourcePosition.line, sourcePosition.column, false, sourceFile[sourcePosition.line]);
                    logCodeTableRow(tbody1, sourcePosition.line + 1, sourcePosition.column, false, sourceFile[sourcePosition.line + 1]);
                    logCodeTableRow(tbody1, sourcePosition.line + 2, sourcePosition.column, false, sourceFile[sourcePosition.line + 2]);
                    logCodeTableRow(tbody1, sourcePosition.line + 3, sourcePosition.column, false, sourceFile[sourcePosition.line + 3]);

                    newDivGroup.appendChild(table1);
                } else {
                    logToOutput('sourcePosition.source not found');
                }
                return;
            });
        }

        function logCodeTableRow(tableBody, row, column, isPrimary, message) {
            if (!message) return;

            const tr = document.createElement("tr");

            const td1 = document.createElement("td");
            td1.style.borderRight = '1px solid black;';
            td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(row));
            tr.append(td1);

            const td2 = document.createElement("td");
            td2.style.setProperty('white-space', 'pre');
            if (isPrimary) {
                var before = message.substring(0, column);
                td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(before));

                const markerDiv = document.createElement("span");
                markerDiv.style.color = "red";
                markerDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("|"));
                td2.append(markerDiv);

                var after = message.substring(column);
                td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(after));
            } else {
                td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
            }
            tr.append(td2);

            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        }

        function downloadScriptFile(filePath) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', filePath);
                xhr.responseType = 'text';
                xhr.send();
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (xhr.status != 200) {
                        console.error(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
                        reject();
                    } else {
                        // console.log(xhr.response);
                        return resolve(xhr.response);
                    }
                };
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 30px;">
    <textarea id="text-input" rows="12" cols="150">
        </textarea>
    <br />
    <button onclick="decodeNow(1)">Run for current deploy</button>
    <button onclick="decodeNow(2)">Run for current deploy (SourceMap)</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="text-output">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```