# When build for prod get error Uncaught NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(a)[D -> v]

Tags: angular

in dev mode everything working ok. 
when I build `ng build --prod app1` there is no any error, but when I try to start app with `npx serve` 
or with `nginx` I get error in console

> main-es2015.e9b3eb4f232c257bd784.js:1 Uncaught NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(a)[D -> v]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[D -> v]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for v!

Is there any way to debug this?

Comment: Do you have custom build or ng-cli based build?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav ng based build (angular CLI)

Comment: According to this post you can disable minification https://stackoverflow.com/a/52712419/453959 then it will be easier to debug