# ng build - ERROR in scripts.XX.js from Terser "f" is redeclared

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, ng-build, terser

I am using Angular 6 to implement a frontend for an ASP NET web application.
Regarding performance issues I wanted to reduce the size of the vendor.js file.
Therefore I found a solution to build my Angular project with following command:
`ng build --prod --base-href "myURL"`
Now I get the following error:

```
ERROR in scripts.XX.js from Terser
"f" is redeclared [scripts.XX.js:2483, 589]
```

'XX' is a hash like `737de149a78`. I´ve read several questions and answers, changing the version of Terser to 3.14.1 did not help.
My first approach to fix this issue was trying to find a variable or module named "f" in the whole project, to see if it was redeclared at any point, but a variable named "f" does not exist.

So my question is: How can I find the variable that seems to be redeclared without going through thousands of files and lines of code? Or is there another way to fix this error?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myProj",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "json-server": "json-server --watch db.json",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.6.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.6.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "^8.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.1",
    "angular-popper": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "json-server": "^0.14.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.1",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

I´m glad for any kind of help.

**EDIT:**

I have a **temporary** solution, that may helps others who have to face this problem, too:
`ng build --prod --optimization=false --base-href "myURL"`.

Why this is not a proper solution in my case:

After I have built my Angular project with `--prod` flag, the project wasn't built correctly, but the scripts.XX.js file was created anyway. In this file were multiple variables named f. As a next step I took a look what the `--prod` flag does (see: https://angular.io/cli/build).

Under further Details (see: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config) I read that enabling the `--prod` flag leads to rewriting code to use short, cryptic names ("minification").

There was also declared, that the application builder uses the webpack build tool (see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/).

So my approach to fix the issue was to disable the minify function of the terser plugin. And this can be done by changing the `"optimization"` in your angular.json file to `false` (see: [AngularCli: disable minification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557090/angularcli-disable-minification)):

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": false,   // <--- change optimization to false
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
```

Of course you can use the `--optimization=false` flag instead.

**BUT**: Disabling the minify function leads to a bigger size of the main.js file, what I was trying to avoid. So for me there is no point in using --prod flag without optimizaion.

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case i accidentally provided a library twice (via node_modules and via .angular.json - scripts). So i removed one them.